# How to convert Scala RDD to Map

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a RDD (array of String) `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MappedRDD[18]`
and to convert it to a map with unique Ids. I did '`val vertexMAp = vertices.zipWithUniqueId`'
but this gave me another RDD of type `'org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Long)]'` but I want a '`Map[String, Long]`' . How can I convert my '`org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Long)] to Map[String, Long]`' ?

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's a built-in `collectAsMap` function in `PairRDDFunctions` that would deliver you a map of the pair values in the RDD.

```
val vertexMAp = vertices.zipWithUniqueId.collectAsMap
```

It's important to remember that an RDD is a distributed data structure. You can visualize it a 'pieces' of your data spread over the cluster. When you `collect`, you force all those pieces to go to the driver and to be able to do that, they need to fit in the memory of the driver.

From the comments, it looks like in your case, you need to deal with a large dataset. Making a Map out of it is not going to work as it won't fit on the driver's memory; causing OOM exceptions if you try.

You probably need to keep the dataset as an RDD. If you are creating a Map in order to lookup elements, you could use `lookup` on a PairRDD instead, like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._  // import implicits conversions to support PairRDDFunctions

val vertexMap = vertices.zipWithUniqueId
val vertixYId = vertexMap.lookup("vertexY")
```

Comment: if you have unique values in your left tuple already, do you need to use zipWithUniqueId?

Comment: @maasg does lookup works across the worker nodes in RDDs?

Comment: @santhosh yes. `lookup` works across the complete distributed `RDD`

Comment: Hi @alex9311, did you found the answer to your question?

Answer (score 8):

Collect to "local" machine and then convert Array[(String, Long)] to Map

```
val rdd: RDD[String] = ???

val map: Map[String, Long] = rdd.zipWithUniqueId().collect().toMap
```

Comment: my RDD has 19123380 records and when I run `val map: Map[String, Long] = rdd.zipWithUniqueId().collect().toMap` I get a lang.OutOfMemoryError. Is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: No. You can use NoSql storage (Cassandra for example) to load your RDD and access it with Map-like interface.

Comment: Hi Eugene, can you please elaborate a bit more on your comment?

Comment: you can use https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector to save your RDD[(String, Long)] as cassandra table. And later use it as fast by-key-lookup

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to convert. The implicits for **PairRDDFunctions** detects a Two-Tuple based RDD and applies the PairRDDFunctions methods automatically.